# Unable to use Html.RenderParial if I reference System.Reactive.Core.dll in my project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to use RenderPartial since I have to reuse code from a different cshtml. So, I use:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewMe"); }
```

But, I get this error instead :(.

Compiler Error Message: 
`EditMe.cshtml(1,4): error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\20f834d3\15233d01\assembly\dl3\a4d6f6b9\06975aaa_caebce01\System.Reactive.Core.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous error)`

Can someone help me with this please? I really don't understand how something so simple in Razor would not compile! I tried in the sample app and it is because of referencing System.Reactive.Core.dll. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: ViewData is used for passing information to views.  The code you have says the partials name is "ViewData".  If that is true, try changing the partial name to something different and see if that helps

Comment: Sorry @Matt Bodily, it was something different. I just used ViewData as a sample. It did not depend on that :(. It is something to do with referencing System.Reactive.Core.dll.

Comment: render partial is done correctly then,  just make sure the partial name matches.  try referencing an empty partial and see if that loads.  I am guessing that there is something on the partial that is causing an issue

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Reactive Libraries and MVC.

Add the following to `<System.Web>` section in `Web.config`:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```